# PSQL: With a table of date ranges, how can I calculate the amount of time that overlaps with a selected date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of date ranges that look like this, I call them `Attempts`:

```
id   |           start            |            end
-----+----------------------------+----------------------------
 1   | 2017-09-09 01:09:00        | 2017-09-09 02:09:00
58   | 2017-09-09 08:35:51.420588 | 2017-09-09 17:01:57.106442
59   | 2017-09-09 17:12:13.644954 | 2017-09-09 17:17:42.186903
60   | 2017-09-09 17:18:51.794184 | 2017-09-09 17:50:09.508929
61   | 2017-09-09 17:19:31.205516 | 2017-09-09 17:20:11.924069
62   | 2017-09-09 17:20:32.320789 | 2017-09-09 17:23:19.973078
63   | 2017-09-09 17:23:53.849006 | 2017-09-09 17:24:23.574369
64   | 2017-09-09 17:24:56.333346 | 2017-09-09 17:27:10.556657
65   | 2017-09-09 17:27:12.605315 | 2017-09-09 17:27:14.680357
```

I want to make a query that will return the total amount of overlapping time in that table and a provided date range. For example, I want to get the total amount of Attempt time in the month of September.

Comment: what if the overlapping interval start in september and end in october?

Comment: That case and the inverse (starting in August and ending in September) are what I don't know how to handle in sql.

Comment: I'm asking whether the whole such overlapping interval should be included

Comment: Only the overlapping interval.

Comment: What result you expect with that sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `input_range` you put the parameters.

First you need to check if a row overlap with your range

```
WHERE "start" < range_end
  AND "end"   > range_start
```

But if that row go beyond that range you reassign the range border instead

```
CASE WHEN "start" < range_start 
     THEN range_start
     ELSE "start"
END as new_start
```

Then sum the seconds beteeen timestamps

```
SUM (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (new_end - new_start)))
```

[**SQL DEMO**](https://rextester.com/NXIT71823)

```
WITH input_range as (
    SELECT '2017-09-09 17:18'::timestamp as range_start,
           '2017-09-09 17:22'::timestamp as range_end
), fix_data as (
    SELECT A.*, CASE WHEN "start" < range_start 
                     THEN range_start
                     ELSE "start"
                END as new_start
              , CASE WHEN "end" > range_end 
                     THEN range_end
                     ELSE "end"
                END as new_end    
    FROM Attempts A
    CROSS JOIN input_range
    WHERE "start" < range_end
      AND "end"   > range_start
)
SELECT SUM (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (new_end - new_start)))
      -- * to see what are you SUM
FROM fix_data;
```

Comment: I've tested it with a few ranges and it looks great! Thanks a ton.

Comment: You could put the parameters direct on the `WHERE` I create the `input_range` cte as part of my solving process.